# Solving $2^{16^x} = 16^{2^x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find $x$ if $2^{16^x} = 16^{2^x}$.

If $x = 0$ we have $2=16$.

$8$ times or $(2^3)$ difference and if $x = 1$ we have $65536=256$.

$256$ or $2^8$ difference. I can't see anything useful in figuring this out.

I have a feeling $x$ must be a fraction. I know only know about logarithm. I haven't learned anything about the number $e$ or $ln$ yet.

Comment: take log base 2, you'll get $2^{4x}$ = $2^{x+2}$

Comment: @Aditya_math so you would want to take $\log_2$ a second time

Comment: @Henry yes, or simply we could just compare powers which is technically the same thing!

Comment: Lets group the $x$'s on one side and the numbers on the other side, it is clear that $x+x=\frac{216}{162}\implies x=\frac 23$. Ok, I'll just be leaving now...

Comment: @zwim how did you derive $\frac{216}{162}$?

Comment: @Edmund it is a joke "*how to get the good result with bad math*", I just wrote $2^{16}$ as $216$ and $16^2$ as $162$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$16^{2^x}=(2^4)^{2^x}=2^{4\cdot 2^x}=2^{2^2\cdot 2^x}=2^{2^{x+2}}$. So
$$2^{16^x}=16^{2^x}\iff 2^{16^x}=2^{2^{x+2}}\iff$$ $$\iff 16^x=2^{x+2}\iff 2^{4x}=2^{x+2} \iff 4x=x+2 \iff x=\frac{2}{3}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$2^{16^x} = 2^{(2^4)^x} = 2^{2^{4x}}$$

$$16^{2^x} = (2^4)^{2^x} = 2^{4\times 2^x} = 2^{2^{x+2}}$$

Now equate the two expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the $\log_2$ of both sides you end up with
\begin{align*}
\log_2(2^{16^x}) &= 16^x \log_2(2) = 16^x = 2^x\cdot8^x\\
\log_2(16^{2^x}) &= 2^x\log_2{16} = 2^x\cdot4
\end{align*}
From this you get that $2^x\cdot 4 = 2^x \cdot 8^x \implies 8^x = 4 \implies x =\log_{8}(4) = 2/3.$

($\log_8(4) = \log_8(2^2) = 2\log_8(2) = 2\cdot1/3$)